# Make pre existing matplotlib graphs into a 2x2 subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, mandelbrot

[image: How the image is defined]

I have made 4 blocks of code resulting in 4 different colourmesh graphs, each defined in this same way. I want to print these 4 graphs together in a 2x2 subplot. Is there a way I can retroactively apply these graphs like that in matplotlib?

Comment: this question is missing a lot of detail. also don't post images of a code. post the code and clear example of the output you'd like

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are several problems with your question, mainly incomplete code, unclear aim (do you want to extract the data from four already generated figures? why not plot them from scratch into subplots?),  and  [image of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).